# What is the best way to represent a schedule in a database, via Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, backup, django-forms

I am writing a backup system in Python, with a Django front-end. I have decided to implement the scheduling in a slightly strange way - the client will poll the server (every 10 minutes or so), for a list of backups that need doing. The server will only respond when the time to backup is reached. This is to keep the system platform independent - so that I don't rely on cronjobs or suchlike. Therefore the Django front-end (which exposes an XML-RPC API) has to store the schedule in a database, and interpret that schedule to decide if a client should start backing up or not.

At present, the schedule is stored using 3 fields: days, hours and minutes. These are comma-separated lists of integers, representing the days of the week (0-6), hours of the day (0-23) and minutes of the hour (0-59). To decide whether a client should start backing up or not is a horribly inefficient operation - Python must loop over all the days since a time 7-days in the past, then the hours, then the minutes. I have done some optimization to make sure it doesn't loop too much - but still!

This works relatively well, although the implementation is pretty ugly. The problem I have is how to display and interpret this information via the HTML form on the front-end. Currently I just have huge lists of multi-select fields, which obviously doesn't work well.

Can anyone suggest a different method for implementing the schedule that would be more efficient, and also easier to represent in an HTML form?

Comment: Could you clarify the scenario a little? What is getting backed up - data on the client? Is there some reason you are not simply storing the next backup date in the database as a datetime?

Comment: Or the backup interval as a timedelta? If you saved the time of the last backup, and the required timedelta, calculation would be a snap.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this. I was going for a cron-like syntax - and then got completely stuck on that path. The plan now is to ask the user for the next run date/time and store that with the delta. I can then use a nice JQuery UI datepicker widget :).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [django-chronograph](http://code.google.com/p/django-chronograph/). It has a pretty nice interface for scheduling jobs at all sorts of intervals. You might be able to borrow some ideas from that. It relies on [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), which you might also find useful for specifying repeating events.

Comment: +1 for django-chronograph, and it uses dateutil to provide a rich time specification language.

Comment: dateutil looks really powerful, but I don't think I'll use it for this project to keep the dependencies down. With the method described above I don't need anything more complicated than a bit of maths!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous—do you mean: *"Back up every Sunday, Monday and Friday at time X."*?

If so, use a [Bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) to store the recurring schedule as an integer:

Let's say that you want a backup as mentioned above—on Sundays, Mondays and Fridays. Encode the days of the week as an integer (represented in Binary):

```
S M T W T F S
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 = 98
```

To find out if today (eg. Friday) is a backup day, simply do a bitwise `and`:

```
>>> 0b1100010 & 0b0000010 != 0
True
```

To get the current day as an integer, you need to offset it by one since `weekday()` assumes week starts on Monday:

```
current_day = (timezone.now().weekday() + 1) % 7
```

In summary, the schema for your `Schedule` object would look something like:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    days_recurrence = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True)
    time = models.TimeField()
```

With this schema, you would need a new `Schedule` object for each time of the day you would like to back-up. This is a fast lookup since the bitwise operation costs around 2 cycles and since you're indexing the field `days_recurrence`, you have a worst-case day-lookup of `O(logn)` which should cut down your complexity considerably. If you want to squeeze more performance out of this, you can also use a bitmask for an *hour* then store the minute.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution.